# In ImageView doesn't show picture from gallery

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I tried to get image from gallery in my application and put it in ImageView, but i get error "OutOfMemoryError"

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:695)
 at kz.app.discount.activities.AddingProduct.onActivityResult(AddingProduct.java:374)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3402)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Code getting image from galery with Intent.ACTION_PICK and onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        ImageView imageView = iVAddProductDiscountPicture;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
                        Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));
                        //TODO: дописать код сжатия изображения
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    alertDialog.dismiss();

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` means that the image is too large to be handled by your device. Load it already scaled.

Comment: @MichaelDodd, file size does not matter, only resolution does.

Comment: @Wladimir Rudnicky please increase  bitmap compress size 10 to 100 and try   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

Comment: You will have better luck if you get rid of the completely pointless `ByteArrayOutputStream`, re-encoding, and re-decoding the image. All you are doing is wasting heap space and reducing your image quality. However, even then, depending on the image resolution and the state of your heap, you may not have enough heap space.

Answer (score 0):

try With This:

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            selectedImageUri =data.getData();
                Log.d("uri:----",""+selectedImageUri);
     if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                imgView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

in onCreate()

```
imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gallary = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallary,LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });
```

outside of onCreate()

```
    @Override
     protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    try{
        if(requestCode==LOAD_IMG && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String []filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imgProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Image view get empty image, but i doesn't get error - progress

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this addresses an `OutOfMemoryError`.